# Can someone explain to Chris, why not to change answers

Tags: discussion

the two answers here

https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17138/3289

are....

A - all points on earth see GPS equally

B - the poles do not see GPS equally

I am in camp A, and my pal Chris is camp B.

Unfortunately Chris edited my answer so it said B.

(This made me incredibly confused when I was re-reading my answer!  :) )

(Obviously I just rolled it back.)

Looking at Chris' [then] last comment on the page *("In the meantime, I look forward to you reporting my edits to a moderator and see what the consensus is.")*, does someone have time [for that]

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

There was a lot of confusion in the comments, but it seemed clear to me when I was reviewing that suggestion that it was changing an assertion (two assertions, even) that the answer made in order to say something quite different, and there is no possible dispute that this makes for a bad edit that should be rejected in all cases immediately. I can only assume the other two reviewers did not notice that, which is unfortunate.

I do think you could have been clearer initially in explaining this, although it did eventually come across in the comments.

There were some useful parts of the edit that I've now re-applied, mostly spelling and terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Joe - your post here doesn't actually ask anything (other than the unspecified "do what Chris asks.") so can you please edit to clarify.

As discussed, we actively encourage people to edit answers. The key piece is not to change the meaning.

You say Chris misunderstood you, and obviously a reviewer must have understood this as well as they approved it the edit.

This is fine - you disagreed with it and rolled back. This all seems to be working as expected.

However, I have to say, in reading your post, it was difficult to figure out exactly what your meaning was so it's probably an easy mistake to make. Yes, I know you as the original author don't think so, but obviously some people do. It may come from the unstated assumptions you have made, which may or may not be the same as the assumptions others have made regarding orbits.

Comment: "Can someone explain to Chris, why not to change answers"

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for answering the question **"The key piece is not to change the meaning."**  Perhaps you should delete everything else as it's more like commentary than an answer.